# How to simplify a sentence with multiple ながら + たり?

Tags: grammar

How can I simplify what the student said in the following dialogue?

> 先生：昨日何をしましたか。
>
> 学生：お菓子を食べながら日本語を勉強したり、テレビを見ながら日本語を勉強したり、お酒を飲みなが  ら日本語を勉強したり、音楽を聞きながら日本語を勉強したり、寝たりしました。

Comment: I meant that I want to remove the redundancy of 日本語を勉強したり so we can save some bytes.

Comment: 〜たり〜たり may be the wrong construct for this type of thing. You're not wrong grammatically, but you end up seeming somewhat overhyped, firstly because of all the「 日本語を勉強したり」, and also because you really went over the top with how many 〜たり you used (Rule of 3 applies to Japanese as well)

Comment: For example, I think in any language you're unlikely to hear someone say "I studied while listening to music, and while watching TV, and while drinking, and while eating sweets, and then I slept." No matter how concise you made the sentence, it just seems superfluous

Comment: By the way, you do need to change the ending of your phrase. It should end as ・・・勉強したり、寝たりしました。

Comment: @Sqrtbottle: Oh I see. I forgot the ending. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「お菓子を食べ**ながら**日本語を勉強し**たり**、テレビを見**ながら**日本語を勉強し**たり**、お酒を飲み**ながら**日本語を勉強し**たり**、音楽を聞き**ながら**日本語を勉強し**たり**、寝**たり**しました。」

The biggest issue with that long sentence clearly is the overuse of 「たり」 and 「ながら」, which is making the sentence look kinda sloppy.  What is worse, you are, without exaggeration, mostly saying 「日本語の勉強」 when you are not saying 「たり」 and 「ながら」.

Thus, we need a ***major*** operation in order to make it sound like it was written by an adult speaker.

For starters, I would suggest something like:

> 「（[主]{おも}に）日本語の勉強や[昼寝]{ひるね}をしていました。勉強は、テレビを見**たり**、お菓子を食べ**ながら**とか、お酒を飲み、音楽を聞き**ながら**しました。」

(I know that is not the kind of sentence a Japanese-learner could arrive at, but hard as I try, I cannot write like a Japanese-learner.  I almost wish I could, though.)

Answer (score 5):

> お菓子を食べながら日本語を勉強したり、テレビを見ながら日本語を勉強したり、お酒を飲みながら日本語を勉強したり、音楽を聞きながら日本語を勉強したり、寝たりしました。

So I think you're trying to say that you did these things:

1 お菓子を食べながら日本語を勉強した
2 テレビを見ながら日本語を勉強した
3 お酒を飲みながら日本語を勉強した
4 音楽を聞きながら日本語を勉強した
5 寝た

And you wrote it this way:

> (1)たり(2)たり(3)たり(4)たり(5)たりしました。

To avoid repeating 日本語を勉強した, I think you can think it as:

1 (1'お菓子を食べる)+(2'テレビを見る)+(3'お酒を飲む)+(4'音楽を聴く)+ながら日本語を勉強した
2 寝た

and rewrite it as:

> [(1')たり(2')たり(3')たり(4')たり]しながら日本語を勉強して、(2)ました。
>   (I studied while doing (1')(2')(3')and(4'), and did (2).)

then you'll have:

> お菓子を食べたり、テレビを見たり、お酒を飲んだり、音楽を聞いたりしながら、日本語を勉強して、寝ました。

This is like "I studied while eating snacks, watching tv, drinking sake, and listening to music, and then went to bed".

If you want to say you took a nap while studying, how about:

> お菓子を食べたり、テレビを見たり、お酒を飲んだり、音楽を聞いたりしながら、日本語を勉強しました。昼寝もしました。

I studied while eating snacks, watching tv, drinking sake, and listening to music. I took a nap, too.